# ng-view not rendering partials in AngularJS v1.6.9

Tags: angularjs, angular-routing, angularjs-routing

I'm learning AngularJS for a project but I got stuck in rendering a partial view. I've made the main page with three partial templates that need to be loaded in the main page. Also created a javascript files to define the module and create the controller. After all this still the partial templates are not loading in the main index page. Also there is no errors in the google chrome console. My Folder structure is as follows :

```
- scripts
 -- angular.min.js
 -- angular-route.min.js
 -- app.js
templates
 -- home.html
 -- courses.html
 -- students.html
index.html
```

My index.html is :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" ng-app="myModule">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8">
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
        <title>Title Page</title>

        <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <script src="scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/angular-route-min.js"></script>
        <script src="scripts/script.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <nav class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
            <div class="container">
                <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
                <div class="navbar-header">
                    <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-ex1-collapse">
                        <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                        <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    </button>
                    <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Title</a>
                </div>

                <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
                <div class="collapse navbar-collapse navbar-ex1-collapse">
                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                        <li class="active"><a href="#/home">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/courses">Courses</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#/students">Students</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                        <li><a href="#">Link</a></li>
                        <li class="dropdown">
                            <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Dropdown <b class="caret"></b></a>
                            <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                                <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Courses</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Something else here</a></li>
                                <li><a href="#">Separated link</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
            </div>
        </nav>


        <div class="container">
            <ng-view></ng-view>
        </div>


    </body>
</html>
```

My app.js is :

```
var app = angular.module("myModule", ["ngRoute"])
        .config(function ($routeProvider) {
            $routeProvider
                .when("/home", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/home.html",
                    controller: "homeController"
                })
                .when("/courses", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/courses.html",
                    controller: "coursesController"
                })
                .when("/students", {
                    templateUrl: "templates/students.html",
                    controller: "studentsController"
                })
        })
        .controller("homeController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.message = "Home Page";
        })
        .controller("coursesController", function ($scope) {
            $scope.courses = ["C#", "VB.NET", "ASP.NET", "SQL Server", "AngularJS", "JavaScript"];
        })
        .controller("studentsController", function($scope, $http) {
            $http.get("http://localhost:8000/api/students").then(function(response) {
                $scope.students = response.data;
            });
        });
```

I've also tried the followings :

```
"<ng-view></ng-view>", "<div ng-view></div>", "<div ng-view=""></div>"
```

But nothing seems to be working.

Comment: The hrefs should look like `href="#!/courses"`. With an exclamation mark.

Comment: @JBNizet thanks man !! it worked !! Thanks a lot !!